# Change content property from dynamically created button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have dynamically created button in C# using XAML.

The XAML:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Grid.Row="1"></Grid>
```

and I had created button with this code in C#:

```
Button dugme = new Button();
dugme.Content = "tap me";
dugme.Tapped += dugme_Tapped;
mainGrid.Children.Add(dugme);
```

How can I now change button Content (text) from "tap me" to "tapped ok" in this event.

```
void dugme_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //should I use binding?
}
```

Comment: Is the event the OnClick?

Comment: I assume you want to do this in the clicked event of the button. You could cast the sender to Button and set the Content property to whatever you want. But I would recommend to get rid of that code and bind the Button content to some property in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you set the `Content` property to `"tap me"` when you create the button, so too can you set it in the event handler:

```
void dugme_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ((Button)sender).Content = "tapped ok";
}
```

That said, you ask in a code comment "should I use binding?" and, since this is WPF, the default answer is "yes". But *how* exactly you would do that here is difficult to say, given the lack of context. It's not clear why you are adding the `Button` instance programmatically (doing which is itself non-idiomatic in WPF).

If guess if you feel you have a very good reason to eschew XAML-based initialization and binding for the creating of the `Button` instance, you may as well continue that approach for setting the `Content` property. In that case, the above example should work for you.

If you would like a more XAML-centric approach, you probably should ask a different question, starting with explaining clearly your scenario and asking how to initialize the button in a more WPF-like manner, as well as how to maintain the state of the `Content` property of that button.

Answer (score 0):

As to whether you should use binding, this being XAML, almost certainly, it makes your code a lot easier to maintain by keeping the view and model separate, though you might have a good reason.

As to changing the text, you can just set the content property of your button in the event handler.

By default, the object that fired the event is passed as the 'sender' parameter of you function, so all you need is this:

```
void dugme_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Content = "tapped ok";
}
```

As your event handler.